# Unobtrusive javascript with jsf components ... how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jquery-events, unobtrusive-javascript

I have some **jsf** '**commandLinks**' on my page. For these commandLinks, there is `onClick` event. Currently I have written onclick functions directly as the onclick attribute of these commandLinks.

As it is a commandLink, it will create html anchor tag and also have some jsf JavaScript attached to it for form submissions. When I write my JavaScript directly in onclick attribute, the jsf will take care of that JavaScript while inserting it's own. But when the same event handler if I attach through jQuery, the it wouldn't recognize and submit the form before executing the event handler.

Is there any proper solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to let your jQuery function do the same as JSF is doing under the covers: wrapping the custom onclick function specified in the `onclick` attribute in another function which executes the standard JSF job of submitting the form depending on the outcome of the custom onclick function.

Here's a kickoff example assuming that all those link elements have a class of `link` and that your custom onclick function is `yourCustomFunction()`.

```
$(".link").each(function(i, element) {
    var originalJsfOnclick = element.onclick; // Grab the JSF-generated onclick function.
    element.onclick = null; // Reset it.

    $(element).click(function(event) {
        if (yourCustomFunction()) { // First call your function.
            originalJsfOnclick.call(element, event); // If it returns true, then execute the JSF-generated onclick.
        }
    });
});

function yourCustomFunction() {
    // ...
}
```